# ¿cómo restringir resultados de búsqueda con like en codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

tengo el siguiente código para una búsqueda en diferentes tablas

```
foreach ($search as $value) {  
  if ($value == 'general') {  
     $term = $this->session->userdata('general');  
     $this->db->like('p.zone', $term);
     $this->db->or_like('p.code', $term);
     $this->db->or_like('p.unity', $term);
     $this->db->or_like('p.price', $term);  
  }  
  if ($value == 'property_type') {
     $term = $this->session->userdata('property_type');
     $this->db->like('pt.name', $term);
  }  
  if ($value == 'zone') {  
     $term = $this->session->userdata('zone');
     $this->db->or_like('z.name', $term);  
  }
```

El termino de búsqueda lo almaceno en una variable de sesión y luego procedo con los `likes`, mi problema está en que el `or_like` de la tabla p me afecta mostrando resultados que deben ser omitidos, entonces, lo que quiero es que la consulta me arroje un solo `like` en la tabla p. He intentado almacenando la consulta en variables y realizando los condicionales, pero algo debo estar haciendo mal.

Saludos y gracias por cualquier orientación que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Te pasa así porque la consulta es muy amplia, al usar or para code, unity y price estás haciendo que registro a registro si $term es igual al like o or_like inmediatamente lo tome en cuenta. Sería bueno que evaluaras el uso del AND o la reestructuración de esa consulta. Si suministras más código quizás podamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Gracias @Huskie por responder, resolví este problema por medio de agrupaciones `$this->db->group_start(); $this->db->or_group_start()`

Comment: Ok me alegra que diste con la solución. Un Saludo